# Access interface variables defined in method

Tags: java, methods, interface

I'll just paste the code then explain what I need. I'm lost as to how to acheive this, and I can't even think of alternatives that fit my code very well.

```
public Transform findById(final int id) {
    final Transform returnTransform = null;

    execute(new IExecutor() {
        Transform returnTransform = null;
        @Override
        public boolean execute(Transform transform) {
            if (transform.getID() == id) {
                returnTransform = transform;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return <returnTransform>;
}
```

What I need, is get the variable 'returnTransform' from inside the interface and use it to return from the 'findById' method.
I can't define a variable in the method, because it has to be final to access within the method: and I need to change it.

One solution would be to define the 'returnTransform' variable directly in the class, but it seems tacky. Any other genius ideas from anyone?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a local class, that wraps the `Transform` variable and exposes accessor methods for it. Then you can use a `final` wrapper instance and you will be allowed to *change* its internal state.

For example:

```
public Transform findById(final int id) {
    class Wrapper {
        private Transform returnTransform = null;

        Transform getReturnTransorm() { return returnTransform; }

        void setReturnTransform(Transform returnTransform) {
            this.returnTransform = returnTransform;
        }
    }
    final Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
    execute(new IExecutor() {
        @Override
        public boolean execute(Transform transform) {
            if (transform.getID() == id) {
                wrapper.setReturnTransform(transform);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return wrapper.getReturnTransform();
}
```

Comment: It seems like a lot more code to acheive something very simple, but that's java :P (It's actually Android)

Comment: You can upgrade to Java-8 :)

Comment: Remove the '()' after the 'Wrapper' class declaration, otherwise works great ;)

Answer (score 3):

You may define your own interface, which would have method to return `returnTransform`, something like:

```
public interface ExecutorWithTransform extends IExecutor {
    public Transform getTransform();
}
```

Then you should use this interface in code, when creating instance:

```
ExecutorWithTransform executor = new ExecutorWithTransform() {

    Transform returnTransform = null;

    public Transform getTransform() {
        return returnTransform;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(Transform transform) {
        if (transform.getID() == id) {
            returnTransform = transform;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

execute(executor);

return executor.getTransform();
```

Also, there's a workaround, which will allow you using non-final variables inside the anonymous interface. You should just wrap your varible with some variable holder, for example, `AtomicReference`:

```
final AtomicReference<Transform> returnTransform = new AtomicReference<>();

execute(new IExecutor() {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(Transform transform) {
        if (transform.getID() == id) {
            returnTransform.set(transform);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

return returnTransform.get();
```

But this is not supposed to be idiomatic way.

Comment: I like the 'hack' to be honest... but I do prefer quality code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class implementing `IExecutor` which contains a field of type `Transform` with getter and which sets it in `execute` - then you can pass an object of this class to `execute` and `getTransform` afterwards.